# Is there a Magento Extension that handles redirects?

Tags: redirect

I am coming from a Joomla CMS which has a built-in "Redirect Manager" (https://docs.joomla.org/Help36:Components_Redirect_Manager) component(extension) that will write to the .htaccess for me. It also will log 404 errors in the Admin panel of "Redirect Manager" and from that log I can create new redirects.

Does Magento have a built in Redirect Manager that is similar or paid extension from the extension site?

Answer (score 1):

1. Log in to the Magento Admin Panel
2. Under “Catelog” in the top navigation, click on “URL Rewrite Management”
   Click on the orange button on the right-hand side of the page that says “Add URL Rewrite”
3. Choose “Custom” from the “Create URL Rewrite” drop-down menu
4. Complete the “URL Rewrite Information” form:

**ID Path:** old-url.html  (For example, if the old url is www.example.com/old-url.html)

**Request Path:**  old-url.html

T**arget Path:**  new-url.html

**Redirect:**  Choose “Permanent (301)”

**Description:**  It is fine to leave the description box blank.

[For More See here.](http://www.cgwebstrategy.com/how-to-set-up-301-redirect-in-magento/)

Comment: From the Joomla Redirect Manager there is a logging function that displays all the 404 errors, thus you have a list of broken pages. I was hoping for an extension that does something similar?